Can I Add Multiple OBR Segments Under a Single ORC Segment in an HL7 Message?
I am working on an HL7 message (version 2.3), specifically using the ORM_O01 message type with the Hapi library (specifically hapi-base-2.3 and hapi-structures-v23-2.3) for message handling. I want to include multiple OBR segments for a single ORC segment. Is it possible to add multiple OBR segments under a single ORC segment or do I need to use separate ORC-OBR pairs for each observation request?
I tried adding multiple OBR segments under one ORC but encountered issues with the message processing. From what I understand there might be restrictions regarding this structure. Can someone clarify whether this is possible and provide any references to official documentation or standards that explain why this might not work?
Here is example of what I am trying to achieve
MSH|^~\&|HIS|MedCenter|LIS|MedCenter|20211007110114||ORM^O01|MSGID20211007110114|P|2.4
ORC|NW|20060307110114
OBR|1|20060307110114||003038^Urinalysis^L|||20211007110114
OBR|2|20060307110114||003050^BloodCount^L|||20211007110114


I am not sure I understood fully, but...
Multiple occurrences of OBR segment may exist depending on HL7 message type and other conditions.
Please refer to this link.

An OBR segment should always be included in orders where a request is made for a given set of observations. For lab tests and diagnostic studies, each OBR segment generally applies to a single specimen or diagnostic study only. With lab testing, there may not necessarily be a 1:1 relationship between test and specimen (i.e different test batteries may have multiple OBR segments even though it is a single specimen). ORU (Observation Result) messages should contain the OBR segment followed by the OBX segment for each observation.

For ORM message:

In an ORM message, the OBR segment is part of an optional group that provides details about the order. When the order placer creates the ORM message, they will include the Placer Order Number in the OBR-2 and/or ORC-2 fields. These two fields should contain the same information, and at least one of the two must contain the placer order number. The message may contain multiple orders for which the rules still apply.

For ORU message:

In an ORU message, the OBR segment is used as a report header and contains important information about the order being fulfilled (i.e. order number, request date/time, observation date/time, ordering provider, etc.). It is part of a group that can be used more than once for each observation result that is reported in the message.

